# Why android CheckBox value is not getting stored in MySQL?

Tags: php, android

I have made a system where I have multiple CheckBoxes and storing the checked value in **MySQL** database using **volley**, however, no value is shown in the database

below is my code for checkbox:

```
if(checkBoxBus.isChecked()){
    checkbus = checkBoxBus.getText().toString();
}
if(checkBoxTrain.isChecked()){
    checktrain = checkBoxTrain.getText().toString();
}
if(checkBoxPrivateRickshaw.isChecked()){
    checkrickshaw = checkBoxPrivateRickshaw.getText().toString();
}
if(inputfrom.getEditText().equals("") || inputTo.getEditText().equals("") ||
            inputdescription.getEditText().equals("")){
    builder.setMessage("Please fill the information");
}
```

Below is my code for **volley**:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("from",from);
    params.put("to",to);
    params.put("travel_type",traveltype);
    params.put("workdescription",workdescription);
    params.put("passcheckbox",checktrain);
    params.put("trainpass",trainpass);
    params.put("passimage",passimage);
    params.put("transportmode",transportmode);
    params.put("payment",payment);
    params.put("finalamount",totalpayment);
    params.put("remaining_amount",remainingamount);
    return params;
}
};
Singleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToREquestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Everything is getting stored apart from checkbox value so please someone can help me where I'm going wrong

**PHP Code**

```
 <?php
include("conn.php");

$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$travel_type = $_POST['travel_type']; 
$workdescription = $_POST['workdescription'];
$passcheckbox = $_POST['passcheckbox'];
$trainpass = $_POST['trainpass'];
$buscheck = $_POST['buscheck'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$rickshawcheck = $_POST['rickshawcheck'];
$transportmode = $_POST['transportmode'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$finalamount = $_POST['finalamount'];
$remaining_amount = $_POST['remaining_amount'];

$response = array();
$sql = "INSERT INTO users2
    (arrival,destination,travel_type,work_description,'passcheckbox',train_pass,
    'buscheck',pass_image,'rickshawcheck',transport_mode,payment,total_amount,remaining_amount)
        VALUES
        ('$from','$to','$travel_type','$workdescription',$passcheckbox,'$trainpass','$buscheck','$name','$rickshawcheck','$transportmode','$payment','$finalamount','$remaining_amount');";
        $upload_path = "uploads/$name.jpg";
        file_put_contents($upload_path, base64_decode($image));
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){

        $code = "Your_data_has_been_submitted";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
<input type="text" name="from">
<input type="text" name="to">
<input type="text" name="workdescription">
<input type="checkbox" name="passcheckbox">
<input type="text" name="trainpass">
<input type="checkbox" name="buscheck">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="text" name="transportmode">
<input type="text" name="payment">
<input type="text" name="finalamount">
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Log the params value and the checktrain = checkBoxTrain.getText().toString(); value.
See what gets printed in the terminal

Comment: display the check value first to insure them

Comment: check the answer  again...if ok mark it as correct @Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//get the value
boolean checkbus = checkBoxBus.isChecked();

// in volley request                                     
params.put("passcheckbox",String.valueOf(checkbus));


//in log
Log.d(TAG,"checkbus" + String.valueOf(checkbus));
```

in php you forgot  to insert the the `checkvalue` `$passcheckbox` `$buscheck` `$rickshawcheck` in DB

Comment: helo sir i chenged my php code but now it is not inserting anything i have updated my php code with other values

Comment: i have added the required values but now it is not inserting anything

Comment: you have to insure all params exists in the inserting command...with their columns  @Smith

Comment: Sir if you are sure that all data sended from android correctly then the problem in php side specifically in inserting

Comment: sir i have checked mysql column names as well it is correct and in insert query i have passed equal number of parameters stil it is not showing anything

Comment: did you verify the checkvalues in log android i mean the value are exists ??

Comment: Hello @AL  Tegani sir i rectified my mistake it was in php thank you for your time and patience and thousand upvotes for your answer

Comment: you are wellcome ..if the answer was useful for you mark as correct @Smith

Comment: sir one more question is that when i upload image via clicking image image is either not showing in uploads folder or showing blank page is there problem with my php code

Comment: use this code to upload the image ..// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image 
if (isset($_FILES["file"]))   
{
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name)) 
{
  //done image uploaded
}
else
{
 //image not uploaded
}
}

Comment: hi sir i debugged my android code and this is the line which is causing problem  params.put("image",imageToString(bitmap));                                                   private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgbytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgbytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

Comment: any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

To read the value of checkbox - follow proper android tutorial.

https://www.android-examples.com/how-to-get-checkbox-checked-value-in-android/

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are not appreciated. The link may get expired in future

Comment: Hello actually i' calling checkbox.isChecked in my button onclick listener and i checked checkbox variable it is storing data